# How to convert '2016-07-01 01:12:22 PM' to '2016-07-01 13:12:22' hour format?

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion, timestamp

Can anyone help me how to convert `2016-07-01 01:12:22 PM` to `2016-07-01 13:12:22` in PL/SQL? I used the following but no luck.

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP ('08-FEB-19 06.41.41.000000 PM', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF') 
FROM dual
```

I expect: 08-FEB-19 18.41.41.000000

I get the following error:

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting the entire input string

Comment: your string is not valid. `08-FEB-19 18.41.41.000000 AM` time is `18.41.41 AM`. How is this possible?

Comment: my mistake. it should be following ;08-FEB-19 06.41.41.000000 PM

Answer (score 5):

Your current timestamp makes no sense, because it specifies the time as `18` hours, which is 6pm, but then it also specifies the `AM` meridian indicator, which means earlier than noon.  So, you may remove the `AM` from your `TO_TIMESTAMP` pattern:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP ('08-FEB-19 18.41.41.000000', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24.MI.SS.FF')
FROM dual;

08-FEB-19 06.41.41.000000000 PM
```

Note that there is really no such thing as 12 or 24 hour format timestamp internally in Oracle.  Rather, if you want to view your Oracle timestamp in 24 hour format, you may do something like call `TO_CHAR` with an appropriate 24 hour format mask:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP ('08-FEB-19 18.41.41.000000', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24.MI.SS.FF'),
        'DD-Mon-RR HH24.MI.SS.FF') AS ts
FROM dual;

08-Feb-19 18.41.41.000000000
```

### Demo

**Edit:**

If you wanted to convert a timestamp string with 12 hour time and an AM/PM component, we can try:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(
        TO_TIMESTAMP ('08-FEB-19 06.41.41.000000 PM', 'DD-Mon-RR HH.MI.SS.FF PM'),
        'DD-Mon-RR HH24.MI.SS.FF')
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Actually the time should be in 12 hr format which is, ;08-FEB-19 06.41.41.000000 PM'. I want the result --> '08-FEB-19 18.41.41.000000'

Comment: Um...the query I gave you is the correct way to do this AFAIK.  There is no internal 12 or 24 hour format, just a timestamp.  If you want to _see_ that timestamp in 24 hour time, then use `TO_CHAR`.

Comment: In order to be independent from current use session `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` you should prefer `TO_TIMESTAMP ('08-FEB-19 18.41.41.000000', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24.MI.SS.FF', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')` - or in whatever language "FEB" is

Comment: I am afraid but this is not the one I expect. What I want is convert '08-FEB-19 06.41.41.000000 PM' to  08-FEB-19 18.41.41.000000. Here you can see the given format has 6 PM and I want it to be converted to 18. can you please help me on this?

Comment: Use: `TO_TIMESTAMP ('08-FEB-19 06.41.41.000000 PM', 'DD-Mon-RR HH.MI.SS.FF PM')` ... by the way, please stop changing your question.

Comment: Perhaps there is confusement because you are using `'08-FEB-19 18.41.41.000000'`as your input, instead of `'08-FEB-19 06.41.41.000000 PM'` that OP presented as his input

Comment: @GoranKutlaca Perhaps there is confusion because the OP has changed its question multiple times since I answered.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's true that OP changed his question after you answered him and I understand your response, but to whoever comes after that change (as I did now) there seams to be discrepancy between OP's question and your (relatively high-voted) answer. As `18 AM` furthermore makes no sense whatsoever (the OP's original input) and thus the answer to his modified question would be far more useful to future readers I would recommend you to add another line in your answer (that would help and accommodate him again) as it would also improve on the future relevance your post.

Comment: Sorry to change the question, that is because I tried to be specific with the question. I still not get what I wanted. I need '08-FEB-19 06.41.41.000000 PM' to convert into  '08-FEB-19 18.41.41.000000'